# Removing lists-within-lists from my prolog code

Tags: list, tree, prolog

I've been trying to solve this problem of mine for a while now but I'm not really sure how to go about it.

For example, let's say I have this "tree" in my database:

```
tree4(b(b(l(Apple),l(Banana)), b(l(Orange), l(Pear)))).
```

I want to be able to query the database so as to retrieve the information within each l() and present it in a list. So far I've done this:

```
leaves(l(X), L) :-
    L = X.
leaves(b(X,Y), L) :-
    leaves(X, A),
    leaves(Y, B),
    L = [A, B].
```

I then query the database and it gives me this:

```
?- tree4(T), leaves(T, L).
T = b(b(l(1), l(2)), b(l(3), l(4))),
L = [[1, 2], [3, 4]].
```

The problem with this code is it generates multiple lists nestled within my original one. Is there another way to go about this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the cost of the `append/3` predicate by using an accumulator to collect the leaves during the traversal of the tree:

```
leaves(Tree, Leaves) :-
    leaves(Tree, [], Leaves).

leaves(l(Leaf), Leaves, [Leaf| Leaves]).
leaves(b(Left,Right), Leaves0, Leaves) :-
    leaves(Right, Leaves0, Leaves1),
    leaves(Left, Leaves1, Leaves).
```

Using your sample call:

```
?- leaves(b(b(l(1), l(2)), b(l(3), l(4))), Leaves).
Leaves = [1, 2, 3, 4].
```

Comment: Thanks Paulo (+1). I was actually going to render another solution without the `append`. You beat me to it. :) I'm still learning not to think first in terms of built-in predicates.

Comment: Thanks for the help both of you, think I understand the jist of it!

Answer (score 2):

As you are describing a list (in this case: of leaves), consider using a DCG:

```
leaves(l(L))     --> [L].
leaves(b(B1,B2)) --> leaves(B1), leaves(B2).
```

Example query (using atoms instead of variables in `tree4/1`):

```
?- tree4(Tree), phrase(leaves(Tree), Leaves).
Tree = b(b(l(apple), l(banana)), b(l(orange), l(pear))),
Leaves = [apple, banana, orange, pear].
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Prolog implementation has an `append` predicate, you could do this:

```
leaves(l(X), [X]).

leaves(b(X,Y), L) :-
    leaves(X, A),
    leaves(Y, B),
    append(A, B, L).
```

So `leaves` will always return a flat list, even if there's just one. This also assumes your tree is strictly binary, as you have it described.

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder about [flatten](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=flatten/2)/2, an handy builtin:

```
?- leaves(b(b(l(1), l(2)), b(l(3), l(4))), L), flatten(L, F).
L = [[1, 2], [3, 4]],
F = [1, 2, 3, 4].
```

As you can see from documentation, its use is discouraged, and you have already received plenty of good hints that allow to avoid it.